# $n$-fold compositions and countability

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory

Consider $\phi:\;(0,1)\to (0,1)$ satisfying $\phi(x)<x$ and let $\phi^n(x)$ denote $\phi(\phi(\cdots \phi(x)\cdots )$ iterated $n$ times. Then $\phi^n(x)$ converges for each $x\in (0,1)$. Hence consider:

$$X=\Big\{ \lim_{n\to\infty} \phi^n(x)\;\big|\;x\in (0,1)\Big\}$$
If $\phi$ continuous then $X=\{0\}$, otherwise it is easy to find $\phi$ such that $X$ is countable $($defining $\phi$ piecewise over countably many intervals $(x_i,x_{i+1}]$ such that $\phi^n(x)\to x_i$ when $x\in (x_i,x_{i+1}])$.

**Question:** is there a $\phi$ such that $X$ is uncountable?

$($perhaps invoking the Cantor set or similar$?)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ be a (necessarily uncountable) $\Bbb{Q}$-basis of $\Bbb{R}$. By rescaling (with elements from $\Bbb{Q}$), we can assume $v_i \in (0,1)$ for all $i \in I$.

Define

$$
f:\left(0,1\right)\rightarrow\left(0,1\right),x\mapsto\begin{cases}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)v_{i}, & x=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)v_{i}\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and }i\in I,\\
\frac{x}{2}, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Note that $f$ is well-defined, because $\big((1 + \frac{1}{n})v_i\big)_{n \in \Bbb{N}, i\in I}$ is a family of pairwise different elements (because of the $\Bbb{Q}$-linear independence of $(v_i)_i$).

It is now easy to see that $f$ fulfills your conditions and that $X \supset \{v_i \,|\, i\in I\}$ is uncountable.

Remark: I don't know whether you can construct an example without invoking the axiom of choice.